# Transform comma delimited list values into a sparse matrix using R

Tags: r

In the new data structure, each segmentId should be turned into a column name. Each personId should still have one row per id. The segmentId cells are a count of how many times the segmentid appeared in the comma delimited list. Example below.

AS IS: I'm trying to transform data in this form:

```
| PersonID | SegmentId     |
|----------|---------------|
| 1001     | 50,61,72,42,1 |
| 1002     | 49,33,24,72   |
| 1003     | 22,22,23,99,2 |
```

TO BE: in this form:

```
| PersonID | 1 | 2 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 33 | 42 | 49 | 50 | 61 | 72 | 99 |
|----------|---|---|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
| 1001     | 1 | 0 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 0  |
| 1002     | 0 | 0 | 0  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 0  |
| 1003     | 0 | 1 | 2  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 1  |
```

Here is the dput:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L
), .Label = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "PersonID"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(c(8L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("10038,10068,1015,103587,1042,108930,11012,11336,11445,11446,11448,11459,11485,12", 
    "10038,10093,1015,108930,11336,11450,11459,11737,11738,12", 
    "10039,10069,108930,11336,11484,11485,11737,11738,12", "10051,108930,11336,12", 
    "10055,11484,12", "1042,108930,11336,12", "108930,11336,11453,11459,12", 
    "segments"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: can you dput your data?

Comment: Is the number of segmentIds always the same for each PersonID?

Comment: Added the dput. Atiretoo: the number of segmentsIDs for each PersonID will usually be different.

Comment: Your column names are `V1` and `V2`. I think you messed up your `dput`. Don't use `cbind` when creating it.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, it seems that the output of `dput` is messed up. Therefore, I considered input data matching just what you mentioned, where for convenience I am taking the person id to be strings (encoded as factors in the input data frame):

```
Input <- data.frame(
    PersonID = c("1001", "1002", "1003"), 
    segments = c("50,61,72,42,1", "49,33,24,72", "22,22,23,99,2")
)
```

My first idea would be to simply expand the data, after splitting the comma-delimited values, and then use `dcast` (package `reshape2`) to put the data in wide format:

```
# Parse the data, such that each row now corresponds to a single 'segment' value
Data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(Input), function(i) 
    data.frame(
        PersonID = as.numeric(as.character(Input[[i, "PersonID"]])), 
        segments = as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(Input[[i, "segments"]]), ",")[[1]])
    )
))

# Convert the data to long format, putting the person id as a column
library(reshape2)
Results <- as.matrix(dcast(Data, PersonID ~ segments, value.var = "segments", fun.aggregate = length, fill = 0))
```

But this does not take advantage of the fact that the results are a sparse matrix, which may be essentially a must depending on the actual data you are working with. Since you mention "sparse"  in the title, here is an alternative solution, although a bit longer, in which the results are stored in a sparse matrix (via package `Matrix`). This solution takes advantage of the input format that is accepted by the function `sparseMatrix` (see the documentation of the package for details and examples):

```
# Parse the data, such that each row now corresponds to a single 'segment' value
# Both the person id and the segment are stored as factors (this is a key point)
Source <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(Input), function(i) # person id and segments as factors
    data.frame(
        PersonID = as.character(Input[[i, "PersonID"]]), 
        segments = strsplit(as.character(Input[[i, "segments"]]), ",")[[1]]
    )
))

library(Matrix)
Results_sparse <- sparseMatrix(
    i = as.numeric(Source$PersonID), 
    j = as.numeric(Source$segments), 
    x = rep(1, length.out = nrow(Source)) # will be automatically "aggregated"
)

# Use the info on the person id and segments (numeric values and the 
# strings for the factors) to used to set column names and add column 
# corresponding to the person ids
colnames(Results_sparse) <- levels(unique(Source$segments))
Results_sparse <- cbind(
    PersonID = as.numeric(levels(unique(Source$PersonID))), 
    Results_sparse
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking `Input` from tguzella's answer.

```
Input <- data.frame(
    PersonID = c("1001", "1002", "1003"), 
    segments = c("50,61,72,42,1", "49,33,24,72", "22,22,23,99,2")
)
```

1: Split segments to separate variables

```
library(splitstackshape)
dd<-cSplit(Input, 'segments', sep=",", type.convert=FALSE)
```

2: Melt to make a single variable

```
library(reshape2)

dd2<-as.data.frame(melt(dd, id.var="PersonID"))
dd2<-na.omit(dd2[,-2])
```

3: Make it wide as matrix

```
dcast(data=dd2, PersonID ~ value, value.var="value")


Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
  PersonID 1 2 22 23 24 33 42 49 50 61 72 99
1     1001 1 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0
2     1002 0 0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0
3     1003 0 1  2  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```