# How to go from long to wide dataframe in R with multiple values separated by a comma in focal column

Tags: r, dplyr, dummy-variable

Say I have a list of movies with their directors. I want to convert these directors to dummy variables (i.e. if a director directs a movie, they have their own column with a 1, if they don't direct that movie then that column has a zero). This is tricky because there are occasionally movies with two directors. See example below. df is the data I have, df2 is what I want.

```
movie <- c("Star Wars V", "Jurassic Park", "Terminator 2")
budget <- c(100,300,400)
director <- c("George Lucas, Lawrence Kasdan", "Steven Spielberg", "Steven Spielberg")

df <- data.frame(movie,budget,director)
df

movie <- c("Star Wars V", "Jurassic Park", "Terminator 2")
budget <- c(100,300,400)
GeorgeLucas <- c(1,0,0)
LawrenceKasdan <- c(1,0,0)
StevenSpielberg <- c(0,1,1)

df2 <- data.frame(movie, budget, GeorgeLucas, LawrenceKasdan, StevenSpielberg)
df2
```

Comment: Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32638410/5325862)?

Answer (score 0):

One option is `cSplit_e`

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
cSplit_e(df, 'director', sep=", ", type = 'character', fill = 0, drop = TRUE) %>%
  rename_at(vars(starts_with('director_')), ~ str_remove(., 'director_'))
#      movie budget George Lucas Lawrence Kasdan Steven Spielberg
#1   Star Wars V    100            1               1                0
#2 Jurassic Park    300            0               0                1
#3  Terminator 2    400            0               0                1
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you!